# Wifi Card not recognized after CUDA Toolkit instalation

Tags: drivers, wireless, nvidia, 22.04, cuda

SO I installed the CUDA Toolkit installation on Ubuntu 22.04

`$ sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-cuda-toolkit-gcc`

Doing `$ nvcc --version` gives the following output:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Nov_18_09:45:30_PST_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.5, V11.5.119
Build cuda_11.5.r11.5/compiler.30672275_0
```

Which indicates the CUDA Toolkit was installed but the version seems quite old...

Doing `shw -C Network`gives the output:

```
       description: Network controller
       product: Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:620-61f memory:622f28c000-622f28ffff
```

Doing `$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi`doesn't give ane output!

Doing `$ sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`gives the following output:

```
Status: install ok installed
```

Any ideias how to fix it?
I would like to have CUDA Toolkit working and the Wifi if possible...